# How to Read Container Registry images from 2 different repo on GitLab inside one server?

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry

I have 2 different repositories and both make images inside their own container registry and I want to use both of them inside my server but as I know to pull images from the container registry I have to make a deploy token then use `docker login -u <username> -p <deploy_token> registry.example.com` to pull the image to use it.
but how can I use 2 different Container Registry on separate repositories ?
should I use `docker login` for both of them? I mean create a deploy token for both of them and then use them? is that even work? 
If I want to be more specific I have 2 repositories containing backend and one containing frontend and both of them are dockerized in my pipeline I create images for both of them now I want to pull these images on my server but each of them has separate deploy token and `docker login` just accept one registry.

Comment: I'd expect you can run `docker login` twice and it would work.  Have you tried it?  What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `docker login` multiple times to authenticate with multiple registries. You are not limited to being logged into only a single registry. In other words, the effects of multiple `docker login` commands is cumulative.

You can also configure authentication for multiple registries using `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`, which is a JSON array mapping registry URLs to authorization information.

See also:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html